# Is it possible to mix two GraphQL queries into one query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using Gatsby as a frontend to a WordPress backend. I have successfully fetched the menu items but I now need to link them to the pages I have created. I have added the Menu Links in my Gatsbyconfig.js but I have no idea on how I can go about mapping it to the menu items at the same time as the menu itself. It ends up contradicting each other. Is this possible to do? I am quite new at graphQL. Never touched it till this project. Below is the GraphQl Query

```
{
   allWpMenuItem(filter: {menu: {node: {name: {eq: "Navigation Menu"}}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          label
        }
      }
    }
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        menuLinks {
          name
          link
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The label holds the name for each menu and the link holds the link to the pages I have created. I am trying to fix this into this bit of code

```
<div>
        {props.allWpMenuItem.edges.map(edge =>( 
            <a href="#" key={edge.node.label}>
                {edge.node.label}
            </a>
          
        ))}
      </div>
```

I am trying to query the menu links change the anchor tag to the link item and then point it to the menu link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, natively each query is a separate entity. However, you can combine queries using [`createResolvers`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/schema-customization/), for further details check: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/28275 (thanks [LekoArts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10164092/lekoarts) for the feedback).

However, you have a few approaches to bypass this limitation. Given that each query is transformed into a standalone JavaScript object, you can always manipulate them using native JavaScript filtering or doing whatever you need. The idea is to create an empty object and populate it with links and labels, in a single loop or using two different, then, in your component, iterate through this object instead of through the `props` like you are doing now.

I can't create a minimal example without knowing the internal structure or without knowing what's inside `menuLinks.name`.

By the way, if you are using internal navigation I would hardly suggest using [`<Link>` component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/), among other things, using the `@reach/router` (extended from React's router) will only render the necessary parts of each component, creating smoother navigation than using native anchor tag, what will refresh all the page.

Comment: That’s not 100% correct, you can combine queries in createResolvers, see https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/28275

Comment: You're totally right @LekoArts , thanks for the feedback